# Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Post()

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi m trying to show data from `db` to `index page` but it says: `Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Post()`

controller:

```
  <?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use App\Post;

  class IndexController extends Controller
  {

      public function index()
      {
          $data = Post();
          return view('index', compact('data'));
          //return view('index');
      }
```

how can i solve it

Comment: by using it i am getting all data in admin panel public function index()
    {
        $data = Post::latest()->paginate(5);
        return view('adminhome', compact('data'))
                ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to call `Post()` as a method/function, not the Model Post, and since Post() doesn't exist, you get this error.

In order to return all posts, using your Post Model, you should write it like this:

```
$data = Post::all(); // To return all posts
```

Or if you want to filter it based on some field on the database

```
$data = Post::where('active', 1)->get(); // Get all active posts (you need to adjust to any field you have on your database)
```

Your code could be something like:

```
 <?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use App\Post;

  class IndexController extends Controller
  {

      public function index()
      {
          $data = Post::all();
          return view('index', compact('data'));
      }
```

Please, read more about eloquent here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax should be:

```
  <?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use App\Post;

  class IndexController extends Controller
  {

      public function index(Request $request)
      {
          $data = $request->all(); //get all input
          //$data = $request->input('testing'); //$_POST['testing']


          return view('index', ['data' => '$data']);

          //return view('index', compact('data'));
          //return view('index');
      }
```

docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#accessing-the-request

Comment: Try to put `dd($data)` in your `index` page view. You can also try to change `return` with: `return view('index', ['data' => '$data']);`

Answer (score 0):

you should modified your code :

```
$data = Post::get();
```

to get all posts

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = Post();
```

add all() method to this line

```
$data = Post::all();
```